# Check if bot has Admin?

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a small if statement to see if my bot has administrator privileges in the server.
[bot = new Discord.Client();]

Any help? 
I tried:

```
if(!bot.guild.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") return msg.author.send(":x: I need administartor priviliages in"+bot.guild.name+"! :x:")
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Discors.js but I've noticed that you've spelt ADMINISTRATOR wrong

Answer (score 0):

`bot.guild` (client.guild) doesn't exist.

`client.guilds` is a collection of all the guilds your bot is in, mapped by their IDs.

You can check if a member / the bot has a permission using GuildMember's `.hasPermission` method.

```
if (!message.guild.members.get(client.user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("I need Administrator permissions!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way possible would be

```
if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
```